# Using a for loop to concatenate columns in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm quite new to Python and I'm trying to use Pandas (in iPython Notebook, Python 3) to combine three columns. This is the original data:

```
       RegistrationID  FirstName  MiddleInitial   LastName    
           1              John       P             Smith    
           2              Bill       Missing       Jones   
           3              Paul       H             Henry
```

And I'd like to have:

> ```
>    RegistrationID FirstName MiddleInitial   LastName    FullName
>      1              John       P             Smith   Smith, John, P 
>      2              Bill       Missing       Jones   Jones, Bill 
>      3              Paul       H             Henry   Henry, Paul, H
> ```

I'm sure this is absolutely not the correct way of doing this, but this is how I have set it up so far in a for loop. Unfortunately, it just keeps going and going and never finishes.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd

from IPython.core.display import HTML
css = open('style-table.css').read() + open('style-notebook.css').read()
HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(css))

reg = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('regcontact.csv', index_col=RegistrationID)

for item, frame in regcombo['MiddleInitial'].iteritems():
while frame == 'Missing':
   reg['FullName'] = reg.LastName.map(str) + ", " + reg.FirstName 
else: break
```

The idea is then to add another column for those with complete names (i.e. including MiddleInitial):

```
for item, frame in regcombo['MiddleInitial'].iteritems():
while frame != 'Missing':
   reg['FullName1'] = reg.LastName.map(str) + ", " + reg.FirstName + ", " + reg.MiddleInitial
else: break
```

And then combine them, so that there are no null values. I've looked everywhere, but I can't quite figure it out. Any help would be appreciated, and I apologize in advance if I have broken any conventions, as this is my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a list comprehension to create the new dataframe column, e.g. [(a, b, c) for a, b, c in *some_iterable_item*].

```
df['Full Name'] = [
   "{0}, {1} {2}"
   .format(last, first, middle if middle != 'Missing' else "").strip() 
   for last, first, middle 
   in df[['LastName', 'FirstName', 'MiddleInitial']].values]

>>> df
   RegistrationID FirstName MiddleInitial LastName      Full Name
0               1      John             P    Smith  Smith, John P
1               2      Bill       Missing    Jones    Jones, Bill
2               3      Paul             H    Henry  Henry, Paul H
```

The *iterable_item* is the array of values from the dataframe:

```
>>> df[['LastName', 'FirstName', 'MiddleInitial']].values
array([['Smith', 'John', 'P'],
       ['Jones', 'Bill', 'Missing'],
       ['Henry', 'Paul', 'H']], dtype=object)
```

So, per our list comprehension model:

```
>>> [(a, b, c) for (a, b, c) in df[['LastName', 'FirstName', 'MiddleInitial']].values]
[('Smith', 'John', 'P'), ('Jones', 'Bill', 'Missing'), ('Henry', 'Paul', 'H')]
```

I then format the string:

```
a = "Smith"
b = "John"
c = "P"
>>> "{0}, {1} {2}".format(a, b, c)
"Smith, John P"
```

I use a ternary to check if the middle name is 'Missing', so:

```
middle if middle != "Missing" else ""
```

is equivalent to:

```
if middle == 'Missing':
    middle = ""
```

Finally, I added `.strip()` to remove the extra space in case the middle name is missing.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment on the "Missing" stuff - didn't notice that in the question.

Comment: This was _incredibly_ helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Hi there - this wouldn't work if I wanted to check for a particular value in a column and then return a pre-defined string in another column (i.e. instead of a value in the array), correct? In that case I would need to revert to a loop like in my original example?

Comment: It would probably work fine with some modification, but you need to post a new question with a more specific example.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add the columns:

```
>>> df.FirstName + ', ' + df.LastName + ', ' + df.FullName.str.replace(', Missing', '')
0          John, Smith, P
1    Bill, Jones, Missing
2          Paul, Henry, H
dtype: object
```

To add a new column, you could just write:

```
df['FullName'] = df.FirstName + ', ' + ...
```

(In Pandas, it is usually attempted to avoid loops and such.)

Comment: The timing benefit is marginal once you add logic to remove 'Missing' from the middle name.  You'll need something like `df.FullName.str.replace(', Missing', "")`

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander - didn't notice the part about `Missing`. Appreciated!